# How to route email to a script

Tags: email, postfix

What I'd like to do is set up an address like something@myhost.com which will take whatever email it gets and run the full message as STDIN into a shell script. I can't seem to get this working though. Tried a couple solutions, including this one:

[How can I route some emails to a script in Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/322657/how-can-i-route-some-emails-to-a-script-in-postfix)

But my setup is a bit different. I've got the Postfix/Dovecot/MySQL setup, so all email is handled by Dovecot, and Postfix reads its maps from MySQL. Whatever I add to master.cf doesn't seem to work. SpamAssassin has a line in there and that's working fine. I'm stuck!

EDIT:
I really wish people would read carefully before downvoting my question. I am using MySQL for my alias maps, so /etc/aliases does not work, I already tried that of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously will work Douglas Land's answer, with a little addition.
Suppose you have only localhost.localdomain at $mydestination in main.cf.
Then add a virtual alias :

```
something@myhost.com -> somelocaluser@localhost.localdomain
```

In main.cf you will need:

```
alias_maps=hash:/etc/aliases
```

Then add to /etc/aliases :

```
somelocaluser: "|/your/script/here"
```

newaliases+postfix reload and you are good to go.

Comment: Doesn't work. I set up a virtual alias foo@myhost.com to point to foo@localhost.localdomain and tried foo@localhost too. It bounces back to me instead of going to the script.

Comment: Also, `mydestination` is blank, and main.cf recommends leaving it blank otherwise it can cause problems. If I set mydestination to my host, I get a warning in the mail.log: `warning: do not list domain blahblah.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains`

Comment: Well add localhost.localdomain to mydestination. don't add the main domain.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Logs? I have same config in multiple places, should work.

Comment: Oh man, it works now!! I don't know what I did wrong before, but it works! It runs the script as nobody:nogroup.. not sure if I can fix that. But this is cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe an entry to a script via `/etc/aliases`, RE:

```
foo: "|/your/script/here"
```

modify `/etc/aliases` then run `newaliases` and reload the postfix process.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using MySQL & alias maps, so /etc/aliases is not even used.

Comment: This link is dead, is there another similar one?

Comment: Here's a cached copy of the content: http://web.archive.org/web/20100417080935/http://jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Procmail. We use this to parse all sorts of mail out to worker scripts and IRC bots for notifications.

[Here is an example](http://linuxgazette.net/issue14/procmail.html) of how to handle email.
http://linuxgazette.net/issue14/procmail.html

Relevant short example done here for ease:

1. Create a local user called `handler`, for example.
2. Go to `handler`'s home directory and create a file called `.procmailrc` containing:

> ```
> :0
> | $HOME/bin/my.script
> ```

This will pass the entire inbound email to the script `$HOME/bin/my.script` through STDIN.

Also here is where I got help with Procmail when I was first trying to pass email to a script: [How to use procmail to get a message into a variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/502050/how-to-use-procmail-to-get-a-message-into-a-variable)

Comment: Link was inline with the text. I've expanded my answer though for ease.

Comment: This doesn't work. Like I said.. local mail delivery is not enabled on this system. This server is purely driven by Dovecot+MySQL for mailbox & alias management. Local user accounts do not register as being able to receive mail just because they exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if sieve supports piping to a script. Dovecot supports sieve scripts.

As alternative you can use "procmail" as MDA between postfix an dovecot. Procmail can pipe to a script.

(that said I wonder why Douglas Land's answer does not work, mysql as backend should not make a different?!)"

Comment: Simple. In the default setup of postfix, in `/etc/main.cf`, alias_maps is pointing to hash:/etc/aliases. In my main.cf, that line is gone, replaced with `virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf`. All aliases are handled via a mysql query. I tried using pipe in the DB too, and that didn't work.

Comment: aliase_maps and virtual_maps are two different things. You should read "man aliases" and "man virtual"

Answer (score 0):

Something that hasn't been mentioned is that you can [use more than one lookup table](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps) (separated by comma or space):

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual.cf
alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-aliases.cf hash:/etc/aliases
```

The first one (virtual_alias_maps), will search for an email and return a username (for example: info@example.com -> info1234).

Then, the second one (alias_maps) will search for a username in your database, if not found, will search it at /etc/aliases. This way, you can still manage your aliases in MySQL and set your scripts in /etc/aliases, and no need to append "@localhost.localdomain" to the local users.

To test if your setup is correct, use:

```
postmap -q info@example.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual.cf
postmap -q info1234 mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-aliases.cf hash:/etc/aliases
```

**Using Local accounts with aliases in MySQL:**

In one of my custom setups, I'm using local accounts for users and MySQL for aliases only. So this is how I set it:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vusers
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vusers
virtual_alias_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-aliases.cf hash:/etc/aliases
```

As you can see, feel free to mix them anyway you want.