# Is it possible to trigger a shell script on incoming emails, can it be done without services like dovecot, postix, etc?

Tags: email, email-server, exim, imap

This question more is for learning purpose.

I'm exploring ways to develop a small email server (in + out).

I have a domain that points to my server as well as mx records and all that stuff...

I also have the open ports 25, 26, 110, 993, 995, 143, 465....

I'd like to activate a shell script on incoming email.

I have apache + php running without problem. I type my domain on a browser => I see my pages from anywhere. (that part is done).

I don't exactly know where to start...

There is tons of stuff when I search

I tried `dovecot`, `mailhog`, `exim` but I'm having difficulty to get them up and running.

My question is more : "is there a way to listen to port x for emails => when a email arrives => execute a script (in the rawest form possible)" ?

Comment: Sure. You can program anything, including an SMTP server, to do as little or as much as you desire.

Comment: @Paul would you know a documentation or starting point ? python, php, .sh, do you have a recommendation? the main stuff I miss it the how to "catch" or "listen" for an incoming file .... Once I get the incoming file it will be easier...

Answer (score 3):

You can start by reading [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321) and [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322) that define SMTP protocol and email message format. Once you finished with these two, you can continue reading all [other email-related RFCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Related_requests_for_comments).

When you familiarize yourself with the depth of the rabbit hole you are going to jump into, you can try [Python simple SMTPD](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html) (deprecated) or [aiosmtpd](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd). You'll also need [email.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) to parse incoming emails and extracting files.

And the answers to the question "Is it possible to trigger a shell script on incoming emails, can it be done without services like dovecot, postix, etc?" are [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/506894/how-to-route-email-to-a-script) (actually, I have misread the question as written "with postfix" instead of "without" but I'll leave the links anyway)